# I am a European citizen with temporary residency in Iran travelling to USA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, iran, residency

I am a European citizen, working on an international assignment in Iran currently. I am travelling in a few days to the USA. I have a 10-year multiple-entry USA visa, which I got since I was in Iran for business.

Now I have residency, even if temporary. No need to hide that at immigration but I'm worried I might be denied boarding should I complete APIS with residency address in Iran. Should I choose my home country as residency and inform the immigration officer about Iran? Or no need to worry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You reside in Iran.  You are therefore probably disqualified from using the visa waiver program.  But you're not going to use it; you have a visa.

There is nothing that would lead to an automatic denial of boarding because of residence in Iran.  You shouldn't try to hide your residence.  If you appear to be evasive, you will create more problems for yourself.

I wouldn't go so far as to say that you have no need to worry.  You'll probably get some extra questions about your activities in Iran.  But claiming a different residence would almost certainly not help you, and it will probably hurt you.

Comment: thank you, just completed my personal information on my Air France Reservation and there it says if you travel with visa enter nationality of passport instead of residency. made a print screen just in case. interesting

Comment: @Daisy of course.  They need to know the country that issued your passport to identify the passport.  (Passport numbers are not necessarily unique across countries, although they should be unique for passports issued by the same country.)  Besides, if you were an Iranian citizen, getting admitted to the US would be an entirely different matter.  But there's no guarantee that they won't also transmit your Iranian address, or the number of your Iranian visa or residence document, to the US.  Even if they do, however, there should be no problem.